# Variable returning null from Angular Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a SharePoint App that is built with AngularJS.
I have a controller that is calling a function in a service and it is not returning a value. I am pretty new at angularJS so I am a bit lost.
My Service:

```
App.factory('uploadAppService', function () {
return {
    currentUserPic: function (myProfileProp) { 
        GetUserProfileInfo(myProfileProp).done(function (data) {
            //The large thumbnail pic.
            var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
            var largePicUrl = picUrl.replace('MThumb', 'LThumb');
            console.log(largePicUrl) //the log here is correct. I want to return the largePicUrl back to my controller.
            return largePicUrl;
        });
    }
```

My Controller call, I want to populate `.imageUrl` with the url from the service:

```
$scope.imageUrl = uploadAppService.currentUserPic("PictureUrl");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because of asynchronous nature of the call value is not yet available when your service call returns. You have to wait until the request finishes. For that your service can return a promise which will be fulfilled when the method returns so that caller waits until the promise is fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your `currentUserPic`function doesn't seem to return a value. `GetUserProfileInfo` indeed returns your largePicUrl, but this value is not used anywhere (if I correctly understand your code).

Shouldn't you use `return GetUserProfileInfo(myProfileProp).done(...);` ?

Edit: But as RaviH pointed, if the call is asynchronous, you'll still have to handle it in your controller.

Comment: You should indeed use `return GetUserProfileInfo(myProfileProp)` and in your controller use `uploadAppService.getProfileInfo(var).then(function succes(data){ //code here }, function fail(error){ //code here })`

Comment: What RaviH wrote worked and its is exactly like you said Morphilos, i have to handle the returned async call in the controller and not in the service. Thank you for all the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see implementation of your `GetUserProfileInfo` service, but i suppose it's a Deffered object.

So after code

```
$scope.imageUrl = uploadAppService.currentUserPic("PictureUrl");
```

finished working - you don't have anything in you variable `$scope.imageUrl` because your factory function does not return anything.

So, at first you need to modify your `factory`:

```
App.factory('uploadAppService', function () {
return {
    currentUserPic: function (myProfileProp) { 
        return GetUserProfileInfo(myProfileProp).done(function (data) {
        // ^
        // Here - @ababashka's edit
            //The large thumbnail pic.
            var picUrl = data.d.PictureUrl;
            var largePicUrl = picUrl.replace('MThumb', 'LThumb');
            console.log(largePicUrl) //the log here is correct. I want to return the largePicUrl back to my controller.
            return largePicUrl;
        });
    }
```

Return Deffered Object, so after it finished working, you could save your image URL by getting it in the `response`.

After you need to write next code:

```
uploadAppService.currentUserPic("PictureUrl").done(
  function (response) {
    $scope.imageUrl = response;
  }
);
```

to store your URL in `$scope`'s variable.